# Installing php5-fpm, missing pool.d directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Novice here, so please be gentle :)

I'm installing Nginx with php5-fpm on a Ubuntu 10.04 box according to this guide by ArsTechnica: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/web-served-part-3-bolting-on-php-with-php-fpm/

Nginx is up and running, it serves static html fine. I'm running into problems with getting php5-fpm to work. I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error, when I look into the log it says:

`connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`

When I go back through the guide it mentions to configure /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.
I don't seem to have a pool.d directory at all, and no file named www.conf.

I do have php-fpm.conf in the /etc/php5/fpm directory that has similar settings to the ones described in the guide (`listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.soc`, etc). Can I use this file or has something gone wrong in installing php5-fpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pool.d/www.conf` is most likely just a file that gets included by `php-fpm.conf`. so you can either create that file and include it in `php-fpm.conf` or just put its content into the `php-fpm.conf` directly.

if you have the lsten directive in `php-fpm.conf` the socket file should be created once php-fpm gets started.

Comment: When I look at /var/run it has a file named php5-fpm.soc (.soc, not .sock). Can this be the source of the problem? I can't figure out wich file references .sock instead of .soc?

Comment: is that maybe just a typo? usually its .sock, not sic, so try changing your php conf to sock

Comment: Yup, turned out it was; once I corrected php5-fpm.conf with the added k everything worked. Thanks so much!!